# RabbitAdmin - Eager Declaration

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring AMQP to set up remoting between different services, as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply). However, as I set a `reply-timeout` on my configuration, the first ever request always fails because the time taken to declare the queues, exchanges and binding exceeds the timeout:

> The RabbitAdmin component can declare exchanges, queues and bindings
>   on startup. It does this lazily, through a ConnectionListener, so if
>   the broker is not present on startup it doesn't matter. The first time
>   a Connection is used (e.g. by sending a message) the listener will
>   fire and the admin features will be applied.

Is there any way the declaration can be made eagerly on startup instead of being made on the very first publish event to prevent the first request from always failing?

Answer (score 7):

If you declare your queues with annotations:

```
@Configuration
public class QueuesConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange("exchange", true, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange());
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("queue");
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

then call the `RabbitAdmin.initialize()` manually on application startup with this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

        rabbitAdmin.initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As we see by that description and the code from the `RabbitAdmin`, the last one just populates the `ConnectionListener` to the provided `ConnectionFactory`.

That `ConnectionListener.onCreate` is invoked from the `ConnectionFactory.createConnection()`.

So, you can handle, for example, `ContextRefreshedEvent` and just do void `connectionFactory.createConnection()` eagerly.

From other side `RabbitAdmin` has `initialize()` public method for the same purpose.

**UPDATE**

Actually `ListenerContainer` does that on its `start()` too. You must declare your queues, exchanges and binding in the app where you a have a listener and make it `autoStartup = true`. To be honest the listener app is responsible for the real Broker entities.

The `sending` app should get deal just only with `exchangeName` and `routingKey`.

Comment: Hmm that seems a little "hackish"... Isn't there a better solution for this? (thank you very much, BTW).

Comment: Updated an answer regarding `listenerContainer`

Comment: We added a similar lazy-connect (default true) option to the Spring Integration outbound endpoints last year. As [you can see](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/1df6d872fa5a66424ee7c7e0638c4c159c4fc066#diff-80aa32dc4ee0f287689cdcc5473f0cc9) we used the exact technique that @ArtemBilan described. We could add a similar option to the `RabbitTemplate` for applications that don't have a listener container. Feel free to open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP). In the meantime, you could add a custom bean that does the same thing.